# Collapsing two numeric variables with NA into one

Tags: r, numeric

I was wondering how I could collapse together two variables. The one has NA wherever the other one has a value. They look like this:

```
 a <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,5,6,NA,NA,9,NA)
 b <- c(NA,3,2,4,NA,NA,1,2,NA,3)
 c <- c(1,3,2,4,5,6,1,2,9,3)
 dataset <- data.frame(a, b, c)
 > dataset
    a  b c
1   1 NA 1
2  NA  3 3
3  NA  2 2
4  NA  4 4
5   5 NA 5
6   6 NA 6
7  NA  1 1
8  NA  2 2
9   9 NA 9
10 NA  3 3
```

How would it be possible to create variable `c` in R not by hand?
They are both numeric variables.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifelse`.

```
c <- ifelse(is.na(a), b, a)
```

If both are `NA`, `c` will be `NA`.